# How to improve my server-client networking. python

Tags: python

I have server - socket code that should pass files from one computer to another.

I dont want to tallk about the "send()"\"recv()" functions, because that is not the problem.

I searched for "How to improve my python networking" in google and find stuff like "struct"\"gevent" and more things like that. but I didnt find appropriate explenation about how its improving the networking speed actually..

So.. except the "send()", "recv()", what function do I can use and why, to improve the networking with sockets...

Comment: Why do you think what you have is wrong? The general answer is threading, though

Comment: @cricket_007 I thought about it. to do threading - one to read from the file to some string, and the other sends the string, while the other one read another chunk... but - for now, without any threading, I get 10 seconds to deliver a 1.64GB file - and i realize from the searching, that i can save more time.. but I dont know how

Comment: Sure, chunking the file into multiple streams would work, however, you'd need to write back to a single file and combine each piece when all threads have completed

Comment: @cricket_007 ok.. so thats easy peasy... So what are all the tallking about "struct" and "gevent"?

Comment: As far as I know, struct is for handling binary data streams and gevent is for asynchronous tasks. Unfortunately, I can't offer any advice as how you'd use them